# Issue in get duplicate value in sum query sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sum

hello friends i have 2 tables like below

```
tab_a --> "unit_info_id"   ,"unit_id"  ,"p_id"   ,"p_bathroom"  ,"p_bedroom"  ,"p_size"  ,"p_rent"  ,"p_isrent"  ,"u_note"  ,"r_id"  , "isactive"  

tab_b-->   "rent_id"   ,"unit_info_id"   ,"t_id"  ,"rent_amount"  ,"rent_note"  ,"rent_date"  ,"rent_time"  ,    "r_id"
```

and my query is as below

```
SELECT a.* ,
 (SELECT   SUM(rent_amount)
 FROM tab_b
 LEFT JOIN  tab_a ON tab_b.unit_info_id = tab_a.unit_info_id
 WHERE    tab_b.rent_date 
 between  '2015-02-03' and '2015-12-03'
GROUP BY tab_b.unit_info_id
  ) AS "TotalIncome" 
FROM tab_a  a ,tab_b b
WHERE a.r_id=1 group by a.unit_info_id
```

when i run above query it gave me duplicate value in totalIncome alias like below image
[image]

as per my current data i have rent_amount only for **unit_id =1** , in **unit_id=2** and **unit_id=3** there are no any data in my **tab_2** table but when i run above query it gave me output something like above image  i need totalIncome as per particular unitwise  so any idea how can i solve it?

***EDIT***

**Tab_a content**
[image: TAB_A]
**Tab_b contant**
[image: TASB_2]

Comment: Are you sure you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN in your case?

Comment: dev.bmax  Yes i need LEFT JOIN because i need all unit which has **r_id=1** which is my register id

Comment: dev.bmax  :see my edit question i add two more snap which include tab_a and tab_2 contenat

Answer (score 0):

It's because you add SUM as an additional row so the SUM always appears at the end as TotalIncome since you GROUP BY by ID. What behavior do you expect?

OK, I didn't get you at first. You have to rewrite that SELECT. Can you post the content of tab_b as you did with tab_a?

Check if this works

```
SELECT tab_a.*, SUM(tab_b.rent_amount) AS TotalIncome FROM tab_a INNER JOIN tab_b ON tab_b.unit_info_id=tab_a.unit_info_id WHERE tab_b.rent_date between '2015-02-03' AND '2015-12-03' AND tab_a.r_id='1' GROUP BY tab_a.unit_info_id
```

Also keep in mind you have typos in what you have originally posted.

Comment: vove :thanks for reply but i need all units which has **r_id=1** which is my register id with using your query it is not show that property which has no rent amount

Comment: vove : see my edit question i add two more snap which include tab_a and tab_2 contenat

Comment: the code I posted for you includes that... between '2015-02-03' AND '2015-12-03' AND tab_a.r_id='1'. It has to work, I checked it on my local